# How to perform a loop action at least once and also when a condition is true

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, pagination, do-while

I am looking for a  Python logical equivalent of a `do while` loop in other languages. I have page results I am iterating through. The results structure:

```
1, 2, 3, 4 , ... NEXT
```

Each element there is a link. only the last page has no `NEXT` element so I have identified `NEXT` as the condition that i need to check for when iterating.

I have identified it using :

`next_link = driver.find_element_by_id('anch_25')`

So I have a function `my_function()` that i want to run on each page where `next_link` exists then click the next_link using a `click()` function. If the element does not exist it means either there is only 1 page result or I am on the last page of results. Either way, I still want `my_function` to run in either case.

So i have:

```
def my_function():
    print "Another result page"

###This is where I am trying to loop through the results pages

next_link = driver.find_element_by_id('anch_25')

if next_link:
    my_function()
    next_link.click()
else:
    my_function()
```

Unfortunately, this is only working for the first page and does not iterate over the other pages.

I have also tried this,

```
while next_link:
    my_function()
    next_link.click()
my_function()
```

It doesn't seem to work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: You never update `next_link` inside the loop, so it will always have the same value it had when you started the loop, and the `while` loop will never do anything different than it did the first time (either exit immediately or loop continuously).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `while` loop with the variable that is set to `True` by default and based on your condition, you may change it to `True/False`. For example:

```
is_continue = True

while is_continue:
    ... # Your Logic

    if my_condition:
        is_continue = True
    else:
        is_continue = False
```

PS: I am giving you the sample example and leaving the rest to you to implement. So, you may implement it by your own know and get the idea about how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the next link **after** calling your function. Then use `break` to break out of the loop instead of using `next_link` as the `while` condition.

```
while True:
    my_function()
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_id('anch_25')
    if not next_link:
        break
    next_link.click()
```

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri and OP,  `next_link `is not a boolean so this line  `!next_link` gives a SyntaxError around `!next_link:` when i run `type(next_link)`  it returns a webelement object ` <class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>` So if it is that type of object what would `!next_link` return? and how could I refine this?

Comment: @TendekaiMuchenje Sorry, thinking in the wrong language, it should be `not next_link`. `not` doesn't require its argument to be a boolean, it will work with any value and checks its truthiness.

Comment: is it just me or there is an issue with this code? For me, when it reaches the last page where the element does not exists, it throws an error and tells me saying the element does not exist. After the break, should we be doing `next_link.click()`? Or should we be doing `my_function()`. Since we want it to do `my_function()` at least once, even when the element is not present.

Comment: `break` terminates the loop, so it shouldn't execute `next_link.click()` when the `if` succeeds.

Comment: Where does it throw the error? Maybe `find_element_by_id()` throws an error to indicate that the element can't be found, so you need to use `try/except` around it.